# Show content with button click without postback

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTaskInfo" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="customAlertDisplay hideTag" id="customAlertDisplay" runat="server">
            <section class="notif notif-warn">
                <h6 class="notif-title">Warning!</h6>
                <p>This task was forced checked out by another user. Your changes will not be saved Site.Master.</p>
                <div class="notif-controls">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="notif-close" id="cBtn" title="Close This Message">Close</a>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lb1" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lb1" OnClick="lbSave1_Click" runat="server">Show</asp:LinkButton>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

CSS:

```
.hideTag {
    display: none;
}
```

Code-behind:

```
public void lbSave1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    customAlertDisplay.Attributes.Remove("hideTag");
    upTaskInfo.Update();
}
```

I am trying to show the `customAlertDisplay` DIV when I click the `lb1` linkbutton without doing a postback but it is not working.

How can I update the code, so when the button is clicked the DIV is shown without a postback.

Comment: This `customAlertDisplay.Attributes.Remove("hideTag");` isn't doing what you think it will. I assume you want to remove the class `hideTag`? In which case you would do `customAlertDisplay.Attributes["class"] = "customAlertDisplay";` which is equivalent.

Comment: If you don't need to do anything at server side when showing that DIV, you could avoid using .net to show/hide it, and solve it via javascript at client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some documentation I was able to figure it out.

Here is what I did:

```
public void lbSave1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    customAlertDisplay.RemoveClass("hideTag");
    upTaskInfo.Update();
}

public static class CE
{
    public static void RemoveClass(this HtmlControl control, string cssClassName)
    {
        var val = control.Attributes["class"];
        val = val.Replace(cssClassName, string.Empty);
        control.Attributes["class"] = val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use c# events without postback, they're always fired at the server. Use jQuery to add/remove/toggle css class instead.

Comment: In this case, SearchForKnowledge means without a full-page-postback. They're using the `<asp:UpdatePanel>`

Comment: @freefaller ,Do u think making a partial postback with an updatepanel, only to make a div visible, is reasonable???

Comment: @Legends, who said anything about reasonable?  The OP asked a specific question, this answer doesn't answer that question.  If you notice the click handler does more than just try and remove css class, it runs something called `upTaskInfo.Update();`

Comment: The `UpdatePanel` does a partial postback, which is by definition a postback.

Comment: You know, sometimes I see questions where you can see that the user hasn't grasped a lot of things regarding his question. So I don't answer it, because it would take a lot of time, and he should make hisself a little more comfortable with programming or whatever.
But in this case here, it's easy to say, don't do it serverside, use javascript, of course if the only thing he wants is to show the div. Which is the case when you take alook at the eventhandler.

Answer (score 0):

Without a postback (even a partial postback), you'd have to rely on javascript.

```
    <div class="customAlertDisplay hideTag" id="customAlertDisplay" style="display: none">
        <section class="notif notif-warn">
            <h6 class="notif-title">Warning!</h6>
            <p>This task was forced checked out by another user. Your changes will not be saved Site.Master.</p>
            <div class="notif-controls">
                <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('customAlertDisplay').style.display = 'none'; return false;" class="notif-close" id="cBtn" title="Close This Message">Close</a>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('customAlertDisplay').style.display = 'block'; return false;">Show</a>
```

I took the liberty of removing the code you didn't need (you don't need anything on the server side btw) and add a click handler for the close as well.

But as pointed out in the comments on the other answer, you'd be much better of digging through the docs to figure out if this is appropriate. Client side validations are client side (you basically don't have access to data on the server) - I'd assume you later want to add some logic on which you determine whether to show or not and if you need to access the server for this, you might as well do postbacks.

And no one uses plain JavaScript now btw, its all jQuery (or the other fancier frameworks)

Happy learning!